# How to wait for all nested async functions to complete in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code in an Android mobile app.  I need to make sure transaction.save() is always finished executing before dismiss() is called. Currently, it only works some of the time. I appreciate any advice on how to restructure this to run like I expect it to.

```
private fun save() {
   lifecycleScope.launch {
      showLoader()
      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         transaction.save()
      }
      dismiss()
   }
}
```

Definition of transaction.save() method. onTripEvent is another suspend function that saves a record in the device database, and sends it to a web API. I won't bother providing its definition.

```
suspend fun save() {
   tripRepository.updateTripSourceItem(this)
   tripRepository.onTripEvent("Updated item etc.")
}
```

Definition of tripRepository.updateTripSourceItem

```
suspend fun updateTripSourceItem(tripSourceItem: TripSourceItem) {
   localDataSource.updateTripSourceItem(tripSourceItem)
   api.putTripSourceItem(tripSourceItem).await()
}
```

Definition of localDataSource.updateTripSourceItem

```
@Dao
interface TripDao {
   @Update
   suspend fun updateTripSourceItem(tripSourceItem: TripSourceItem)
}
```

Definition of api.putTripSourceItem

```
interface api {
   @POST("apiEndPoint")
   fun putTripSourceItem(
      @Body body: TripSourceItem
   ): Deferred<List<StatusResponse>>
}
```

I know it's best practice to use withContext(Dispatchers.IO) when accessing the database, but which function do I need that in? The top level `save()` function, `transaction.save()`, `tripRepository.updateTripSourceItem()`, or all of the above? I thought about putting something like this in every function, but it seems like overkill.

```
suspend fun save()
   withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         awaitAll(
             async { tripRepository.updateTripSourceItem(this@TripSourceItem) },
             async { tripRepository.onTripEvent("Updated item etc.") }
         )
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `suspend` from your `updateTripSourceItem` in your DAO?

Comment: @Kiltos G. This seems to have worked, but why does it? Kotlin docs on "Composing suspending functions" say that suspend functions are sequential by default.

Comment: They are sequential but the programming flow is not returning after they happen.
I suspect that inside Room a launch is happening and the flow is returned to you before the database is actually updated.
Let me write a proper answer you can accept

Comment: "I won't bother providing its definition." But I think that's the code where your problem is, so you should include it.

Comment: Tenfour04, the code for onTripEvent is functionally equivalent to what I already provided. It contains two functions, one to update the database (with a suspended function in the TripDao), and one to send data to the API, that returns a deferred object that is awaited. I don't think there's anything else to learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `suspend` in your `updateTripSourceItem` in your DAO.
When doing that, you are saying to Room "Make sure you do this at your own time, don't bother me or make me wait"

Since you want to wait until the database is properly updated, removing the suspend will do the trick and you won't need to do boilerplate code with awaits

Comment: This is false. `suspend` still waits for the write to be completed before it returns. It just doesn't block the thread while waiting. Something else must be going on in code we haven't been shown by OP that is leading to their unexpected results.

Comment: I haven't dived to the inners of Room, so I cannot be 100% certain what exactly it does behind the scenes. But I have experienced this problem a few times and whenever it was crucial that the database write had happened before returning, suspend was messing it up. This does not mean I stopped using suspend completely, when you suspend on the DAO your database methods are returning faster and I think that there's some queuing that's happening from Room Dao for performance reasons

Comment: If it's queuing, then the next read should happen after the current write, so I wouldn't expect the problems the OP is talking about. But I can't refute the issue you're describing. I haven't architected my projects in a way where I would have to confirm a write before doing something else. Seems really sketchy if that's how they designed it. RyanB, if you do remove `suspend`, then it becomes necessary to wrap the call in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`, but if you use `suspend`, that's totally unnecessary. Sounds like using withContext and a blocking call is the safe choice here.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap the save call with async.

```
private fun save() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        showLoader()
        async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            transaction.save()
        }.await()
        dismiss()
    }
```